# Why am I getting undefined error for map method while getting array as a prop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This is what I'm passing as a prop

```
<Card  tags={ ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "React"] } />
```

Here I'm getting the prop

```
const Card = (props) => {
const { tags } = props; return (
<Cardstyled> <Tags>
{tags.map((tag) => ( <Tag>{tag}</Tag> ))}
</Tags>
</Cardstyled>
)
```

Everything seems fine but I'm still getting the undefined error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its not define at the rendering time, do:

```
{tags && tags.map((tag) => ( <Tag>{tag}</Tag> ))}
```